# Is there a way for Windows to return the path to a directory as Linux does?

Tags: linux, r, windows, path

In Windows a path to a directory is something like:
C:\Users\Name

In Linux it should be something like: 
/home/name

In the R programming language backslashes are an escape character, therefore a path (even on a Windows system) must be written either as C:/Users/Name or C:\\Users\\Name. When the path is too long it is rather tiring to retype every slash.

Is there anyway in which Windows returns the path with double backslashes or one slash? 
If not, is there a simple way in R to change the path so that R can understand it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running interactively you can copy the windows path to the clipboard then use:

```
normalizePath(readClipboard(), "/")
```

This will return a unix style path.

Example `C:\Users\john\Dropbox`. Highlight right click and copy in windows. Then run:

```
> normalizePath(readClipboard(), "/", mustWork = FALSE)
[1] "C:/Users/john/Dropbox"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is highly useful if I want to change my working directory of read some text file in another folder.

Comment: But I'm noticing that this method will only work by reading the clipboard. Otherwise I'll get this error:

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Comment: The R parser interpretes single backslashes as escaping so what you allude to i.e. taking a windows path with single backslashes as input and processing it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gsub("/", "//", getwd())
```

Output:

```
[1] "C://Users//tbiegeleisen//Documents"
```

Comment: Thank you. This one is very useful in case I want to just get the working directory. But I'm not sure I could use it if I want to change it. Of course, instead of using getwd() I suppose I can copy the directory I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

to navigate through directories in R, you can also use the foldernames to get into a windows folder and .. to go back to the parent folder
e.g.

```
    setwd("new")
    setwd("..")
```